# Enviar y guardar imágenes en Django por método POST

Tags: django, post

Lo que estoy intentado realizar es cargar una imagen a Django ya que tengo un método con un atributo `ImageField()`. A la imagen "la mando" con un método POST a través del cliente Axios pero Django no me crea ni siquiera la carpeta **`/media`**.

¿Por qué *DJango* no me crea si quiera la carpeta **`/media`** en el directorio?

A su vez en la función `completeInfo(request)`, muestro en consola el archivo que me llega y me devuelve esto:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: blob (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

¿Hay algo que se me está pasando por alto?

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static', 'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static', 'static-only')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static', 'static'),
)
```

**urls.py** (en **`completeInfo/`** es el url de donde se envía la imagen):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('completarinfo/',completeInfo)
]
```

**Models.py:**

```
class clientData(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    client_picture=models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='media/')  

    def __str__(self):
        return selft.user.user
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms 
from .models import *

class clientDataForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    class Meta: 
        model = clientData 
        fields = ['name', 'client_picture']
```

**views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt 
def completeInfo (request): 
     print(request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = clientDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            return HttpResponse('successfully uploaded') 
    else: 
        form = clientDataForm() 
    return HttpResponse("imagen")
```

Answer (score 1):

no he trabajado directamente con axios, pero suponiendo que no debería de cambiar algo en Django que esta funcionando como backend y revisando un poco tu código no veo nada malo, el posible error esta aquí pero si pudieras postear el código de tu formulario seria mejor. Aquí tienes:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: blob (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

El nombre de tu campo input para archivos debe de tener de name='image' cuando debería de ser 'client_picture' que es el nombre de tu campo en tu modelo. Te comento esto por que en tu dict debería de aparecer:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'client_picture': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: blob (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

Y así el modelform sepa que hacer con esa información que esta recibiendo.

También a modo de debug has esto en tu view del form para poder ver si esta pasando las validaciones:

if form.is_valid():
form.save()
return HttpResponse('successfully uploaded')
else:
# Imprimir errores de validación del formulario
print(form.errors)

Y tal vez solo unas sugerencias para que continúes mejorando, en tu settings.py primero ponlo así para tener un mejor orden y puedas referenciar mejor el BASE_DIR

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Con respecto a tus urls.py es importante que agregues estas lineas para poder servir tus archivos en modo debug:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

En tus modelos, solo como comentario en esta linea:

```
client_picture=models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='media/')
```

Cuando subas un archivo lo vas a encontrar dentro de la carpeta media/media/ ya que la carpeta que especifiques dentro de upload_to será creada dentro del directorio MEDIA_ROOT.

Espero esto te sea de ayuda. Saludos.